# show post content (wordpress) in a div (above) when clicked on

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a row with 3 columns, in one of them i show a mini_post_list with the 3 recent post.

I want to show the whole post content when i click on the title of the mini post.
Where do i make this changes?

```
<ul class="mini-posts-list ">
<li class="mini-post-holder clearfix list-item-0">
    <div class="mini-post-content">
        <h4>
            <a href="http://linktopost1" title="Title">THE TITLE</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="mini-post-meta">
            <time datetime="2016-04-18T08:12:51"><span>April 18, 2016</span></time>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum ipsum…</div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="mini-post-holder clearfix list-item-1">
    <div class="mini-post-content">
        <h4>
            <a href="http://linktopost2" title="Title2">THE TITLE2</a>
        </h4>
        <div class="mini-post-meta">
            <time datetime="2015-09-09T20:28:57"> 
                <span>September 9, 2015</span>
            </time>
        </div>
        <div class="excerpt">lorum lorum lorum lorum lorum ipsum…dfsdafasdfasdf</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

so when i click on "http://linktopost1" the whole post content will show on a div above or on a popup.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a onclick event to the title, and a javascript function triggered by this onclick. This function should either create the popup or append div to your html. It's better to have unique ids for each title so you know which post should show.